# How to send ESC/POS pulse command to open cashe drawer

Tags: java, escpos

I have Star TSP100 thermal printer connected on the network with ESC/POS activated.

I've created a simple WebSocket server in order to communicate with that printer and send it ESC/POS commands. Every commands seems to work so far, except for the "pulse". The printer is connected to a cash drawer and I can open it via the driver configuration utility software but not with the ESC/POS command.

This is my code:

```
PrintService printService = findPrintService(PRINTER_NAME);
DocPrintJob printJob = printService.createPrintJob();

ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

try {
        outputStream.write(new byte[]{0x1b,0x45,0x01}); // Bold
        outputStream.write("Hello".getBytes());
        outputStream.write(new byte[]{0x1B, 0x64, 0x02}); // Cut
        outputStream.write(new byte[]{0x1B, 0x70, 0x00, (byte) 0xFF, (byte) 0xFF}); // Open cash drawer
        outputStream.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
}

ByteArrayInputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
DocPrintJob finalPrintJob = printJob;
Doc doc = new SimpleDoc(inputStream, DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE, null);

finalPrintJob.print(doc, new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet());
```

The command "bold" and "cut" are working but not the one for opening the cash drawer.

This command should point to the pin connector #2. I also tried with the connecter #5 by updating `0x00` with `0x01` but it still the same.

Any idea what could be wrong ?

Comment: It looks like you are using the printing system of the operating system. In other words, you go through some generic driver. This driver may cut some of the commands. Check that what you pass as commands reaches the printer. Also check if you are entering the command correctly (it happens to confuse 0x01 with 1)

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution: `outputStream.write(new byte[]{0x07});` to open the cash drawer.